# extracting data from from xml file using Python

Tags: python, xml, soap

I am trying to extract some data from a file:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <d2LogicalModel xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://datex2.eu/schema/2/2_0" modelBaseVersion="2">
        <exchange>
            <supplierIdentification>
                <country>nl</country>
                <nationalIdentifier>NDW-CNS</nationalIdentifier>
            </supplierIdentification>
        </exchange>
        <payloadPublication xsi:type="MeasuredDataPublication" lang="nl">
            <publicationTime>2014-12-04T06:59:55.000Z</publicationTime>
            <publicationCreator>
                <country>nl</country>
                <nationalIdentifier>NDW-CNS</nationalIdentifier>
            </publicationCreator>
            <measurementSiteTableReference id="NDW01_MT" version="662" targetClass="MeasurementSiteTable"/>
            <headerInformation>
                <confidentiality>noRestriction</confidentiality>
                <informationStatus>real</informationStatus>
            </headerInformation>
            <siteMeasurements>
                <measurementSiteReference id="GEO03_D4T-RWS_T_0317_ID_324" version="3" targetClass="MeasurementSiteRecord"/>
                <measurementTimeDefault>2014-12-04T06:58:00Z</measurementTimeDefault>
                <measuredValue index="1">
                    <measuredValue>
                        <basicData xsi:type="TravelTimeData">
                            <travelTimeType>best</travelTimeType>
                            <travelTime numberOfInputValuesUsed="100" standardDeviation="7">
                                <duration>34</duration>
                            </travelTime>
                        </basicData>
                    </measuredValue>
                </measuredValue>
            </siteMeasurements>
            <siteMeasurements>
                <measurementSiteReference id="GEO01_Z_RWSTRN054" version="1" targetClass="MeasurementSiteRecord"/>
                <measurementTimeDefault>2014-12-04T06:58:00Z</measurementTimeDefault>
                <measuredValue index="1" xsi:type="_SiteMeasurementsIndexMeasuredValue">
                    <measuredValue xsi:type="MeasuredValue">
                        <basicData xsi:type="TravelTimeData">
                            <travelTimeType>best</travelTimeType>
                            <travelTime numberOfIncompleteInputs="0" numberOfInputValuesUsed="7" standardDeviation="0.71" supplierCalculatedDataQuality="100.0">
                                <duration>56</duration>
                            </travelTime>
                        </basicData>
                    </measuredValue>
                </measuredValue>
            </siteMeasurements>
           .
           .
           .
           .
           .
           <siteMeasurements>
                <measurementSiteReference id="RWS01_MONIBAS_0091hrr0350ra0" version="1" targetClass="MeasurementSiteRecord"/>
                <measurementTimeDefault>2014-12-04T06:58:00Z</measurementTimeDefault>
                <measuredValue index="1" xsi:type="_SiteMeasurementsIndexMeasuredValue">
                    <measuredValue xsi:type="MeasuredValue">
                        <basicData xsi:type="TravelTimeData">
                            <travelTimeType>best</travelTimeType>
                            <travelTime numberOfIncompleteInputs="0">
                                <duration>23</duration>
                            </travelTime>
                        </basicData>
                    </measuredValue>
                </measuredValue>
            </siteMeasurements>
        </payloadPublication>
    </d2LogicalModel>
</soap:Body>
```

What i am trying to do is use Python to extract from each

```
             <siteMeasurements>
                <measurementSiteReference id="RWS01_MONIBAS_0091hrr0350ra0" version="1" targetClass="MeasurementSiteRecord"/>
                <measurementTimeDefault>2014-12-04T06:58:00Z</measurementTimeDefault>
                <measuredValue index="1" xsi:type="_SiteMeasurementsIndexMeasuredValue">
                    <measuredValue xsi:type="MeasuredValue">
                        <basicData xsi:type="TravelTimeData">
                            <travelTimeType>best</travelTimeType>
                            <travelTime numberOfIncompleteInputs="0">
                                <duration>23</duration>
                            </travelTime>
                        </basicData>
                    </measuredValue>
                </measuredValue>
            </siteMeasurements>
```

the value of attribute 'id' from 'measurementSiteReference' and the text content of 'duration'

I am using Python for this. my code so far:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
tree = ET.ElementTree(file='track.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for elem in tree.iter():
   print elem.tag, elem.attrib
```

But i am having difficulties extracting these values. I don't have any experience with Python.

How can i iterate through 'siteMeasurements' and get the value of 'id' attribute of measurementSiteTableReference and the text content of 'duration'

please give me some advice to help me on my way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have missing `</soap:Envelope>` tag at the bottom of the `xml` file or you may not have copy pasted.
Anyway, after putting the tag in and also adding following `xml` tag at the top (1st line) I was able to run it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

First we need to figure out what elements can we iter on.

```
>>> for i in root.iter():
    print i
```

Which gives listing as below (truncated)

```
<Element '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope' at 0x29e4170>
<Element '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body' at 0x29e4190>
|
|
<Element '{http://datex2.eu/schema/2/2_0}measurementSiteTableReference' at 0x29e4510>
|
|
<Element '{http://datex2.eu/schema/2/2_0}duration' at 0x29e4750>
```

Once we have these elements, we simply iter over desired elements to get their key/value pairs.

**Code**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
data_file = 'soapData2.xml'
tree = ET.parse(data_file)
root = tree.getroot()


t1 = "{http://datex2.eu/schema/2/2_0}measurementSiteReference"
t2 = "{http://datex2.eu/schema/2/2_0}duration"

print "measurementSiteReference ", ": duration"
for e1, e2 in zip(root.iter(t1), root.iter(t2)):
   print e1.attrib['id'] , ":", e2.text
```

**Result**

```
>>> 
measurementSiteReference  : duration
GEO03_D4T-RWS_T_0317_ID_324 : 34
GEO01_Z_RWSTRN054 : 56
RWS01_MONIBAS_0091hrr0350ra0 : 23
>>>
```

Comment: yes,with copy paste i missed soap:envelope, your solution worked perfectly. and it was especially good because of your explanation which made me understand what is done to come to the solution.